# LIMIT: How to approach this problem?

Tags: limits

[image]

I tried solving this by doing $division$ $by$ $x$, for all the numerators and the denominators. Though for $(1+2/x)^5$ i observed that $1^∞$ and so that part was $e^2 $. But all the denominator is turing out to be 0, in whatever way i try to solve. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense to call that expression "$f(x)$" since it is not a function of $x$.

---

Note that
$$\frac{x^5}{(x+1/x)^5} = \frac{1}{(1 + 1/x^2)^5} \to 1.$$
Similarly,
$$\frac{(\log x)^6}{(\log x + 1/\log x)^6} \to 1.$$
Finally,
$$(1+2/x)^x \to e^2.$$

Thus
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(x \log x + x)^5(1+2/x)^x}{(x+1/x)^5 (\log x + 1/\log x)^6}
= e^2 \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(x \log x + x)^5}{x^5 (\log x)^6}
= e^2 \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(1 + \log x)^5}{(\log x)^6} = \cdots$$

Comment: @HIRAKMONDAL The numerator behaves like $(\log x)^5$

Comment: so 1/∞ , should be 0 right?